# Determine a point based on another point and angle given

Tags: swift, geometry, polar-coordinates

I was able to identify a point (yellow) in the arc segment using :

```
let incrementAngle: CGFloat = (CGFloat.pi / 6)
let ratio :CGFloat = CGFloat.pi / 6
let origin = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
let initialAngle = incrementAngle/2 

let point = CGPoint(x: origin.x + cos(CGFloat(i) * incrementAngle) * radius * 1.5 * ratio, y: origin.y + sin(CGFloat(i) * incrementAngle) * radius * 1.5 * ratio)
```

I want to obtain a point which is inside the arc segment(red circle) and at initialAngle i.e. in mid of the arc segment.

[image]

Comment: You’ve got the correct basic pattern (x = r * cos(θ); y = r * sin(θ)). What isn’t working? What did you try? What result are you getting for the red circle? What were you expecting?

Comment: BTW, don’t use `frame` when getting coordinates within a view (because the `frame` is defined in the coordinate system of the superview, so if this view’s origin isn’t 0,0, then the coordinates will be off). So, if you want the `CGPoint` for center within the current view’s coordinate system, you’d use `let point = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)`.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your response, I tried to identify the  new point using `let transformedPoint = CGPoint(x: ((point.x * cos(initialAngle)) - (point.y * sin(initialAngle))), y: ((point.y * cos(initialAngle)) + (point.x * sin(initialAngle))))` but it doesn't work, Maybe I am missing something in terms of formulae.

Comment: Whenever you use `cos` or `sin`, you multiply it by the radius (the distance from the center), not `x` or `y`. E.g. `CGPoint(x: point.x + radius * cos(angle), y: point.y + radius * sin(angle))`, where `point` is the center of the circle/arc. (I’m not using `origin` for the center of the circle, as that’s too easily confused with the `origin`, the upper left corner, of a `CGRect`.)